# How to configure Windows 7 in live mode (readonly C:) like Linux

Tags: windows-7, power-supply, read-only

I usually create headless box with a raw Debian and AUFS file system to set the CF card in read-only mode. All is load in RAM and not change append on CF card.
So i can safely shutdown the box by unplug the power supply and run on battery, etc...

Now i want to do the same headless box with a Windows 7 but i don't know if it's possible. I want the box with Windows 7 can be shutdown safely by unplug the power supply without destroying the file system or got a long checkdisk at the next reboot.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I found usefull information about specific version of Windows, named "Windows Embedded" here : http://www.ni.com/white-paper/13048/en/

> ...With WES7, you can eliminate or manage disk corruption during power failure or system crashes with the Embedded Enabling Features (EEFs). These features are unique to the Windows Embedded Standard product family, including WES7...

There is a lot of "Windows Embedded" version, look at Wikipedia for a synthesis : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded